# Download page as PPT in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf, powerpoint

I am planning to create a React frontend which handles HTML presentations. Besides letting the users present online, they should also be able to download their HTML presentation as PPT (like Google Slides).

I have not yet decided on what package to use for creating the presentations, but most of the packages seem to only support the typical print-download (the PDF that is converted from the HTML when you press `cmd/ctrl` + `P`). One exception is [PptxGen](https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/html2pptx/), but that package is not an option for me (because of reasons not related to this question).

Is there a way for me to download a HTML page to PPT?

(There are multiple ways to download html to PDF - [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF) being one. If it's cumbersome to download html as PPT, perhaps it's possible to converting html -> PDF -> PPT and then download it? Any advice?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after extensive searching, I did not find any other open-source library that handles direct HTML-to-PPT conversions, apart from [PptxGenJS](https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/html2pptx/), so we can conclude that if you want a direct conversion, that's your only option.

There are some other ways to do this though, one that you mentioned is converting to PDF, then to PPT. I have found a service that can do both conversions, called [Cloudmersive](https://www.cloudmersive.com/file-processing-api). They seem to have a [free tier](https://www.cloudmersive.com/pricing-small-business), and a [Javascript API client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudmersive-convert-api-client) that you can use from your frontend, so this is probably worth giving a try. If this managed service also doesn't suit your needs for any reason, you can still handle the conversions yourself, for example, with [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF) and
[pdf-officegen](https://github.com/SpiderStrategies/pdf-officegen).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! It seems surprisingly challenging to achieve. Cloudmersive seems promising, I'll check it out!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, in general, conversions between fundamentally different formats are challenging. If you don't receive more answers, please consider accepting mine